# Can't connect mysql with only golang

Tags: mysql, go

I can't connect to mysql with golang.
I can connect it with PHP or with terminal to same user
But when i try with golang it says:
`Error 1045: Access denied for user 'ekin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

My code:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "ekin:dbpassword@/table")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've imported right lib

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

)
```

Then can set up your connection and config or verify it, like below:

```
DB, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "root:123456@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")
// set max connection
DB.SetConnMaxLifetime(100)
// set max idle connections
DB.SetMaxIdleConns(10)
// verify the connection
if err := DB.Ping(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("open database fail")
    return
}
fmt.Println("connnect success")
```

Hope it can help you! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

User 'akin' does not have enough permission to read from database 'table'. Grant proper permission from root user.

Can look here to find out how to grant permission.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/access-control.html